# конвертировать String в int (java)

Tags: java, android

Делаю калькулятор на *java*. После внесения строки, для расчета, пытаюсь ее конвертировать в цифры. На языке СИ было бы легко, там `char` легко конвертировать в int, а тут строка получается в `String`, и как ее переработать в `int`  непонятно. `String` на массив непохож. Если пытаться отображать в виде: `String[1],String[2],String[3]...` - ошибка. Можно ли, как-то, `String` разбить на символы и конвертировать в таблицу соответствующих значений типа `int`? ( вывести символы в числа)

Comment: `String.charAt` и `Integer.parseInt`? Не?

Answer (score 8):

очень просто:
`int num = Integer.parseInt("12345");`

Answer (score 7):

Строка (`String`) в **Java** это ООП обёртка над над массивом примитивов-знаков (`char`).

Таким образом, вы можете разложить `String` на массив `char` методом `String#toCharArray()`:

```
String string = "Строка суть массив букв";
char[] charArray = string.toCharArray();
System.out.println(charArray[0]);//выведет "C"
```

Также есть статический метод `parseInt` у класса `Integer`, коий принимает строку и выдаёт число.

```
String string = "42";
int awesomeParsedInteger = Integer.parseInt(string);
System.out.println(awesomeParsedInteger);//выведет "42"
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, но что делать если число в строке дробное, например: 42.4? Выполнять двойную конвертацию с округлением, как-то громоздко. P.S. Дробь не важна, нужно только целое.